# Use an image's url as argument in update_field function

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to do the following. I have an acf image field that I want to automatically fill with an image's url that I get from an API. In order to do so, I am trying to use the `update_field` function.

My code looks like this:

`update_field( $field, 'myimagesurl.jpg', $post_id );`

Unfortunately, my code does not work, the acf field in my admin still empty. When I use an image url the function works properly.

Can you please help me in making the function work with an image url?
Thank you

Comment: Where do you place this `update_field` code? And are you sure that as `$field` variable you pass a string with either field name or field key?

Comment: The image field in ACF, regardless of the output settings, only stores an ID of the image in the database. So if you want to set it to an external image you need to upload the image to the media library using [`media_handle_upload`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) and then set the field to the new file's ID. If you don't want to upload it, then your field needs to be a URL field.

Comment: My function is written in a function that is triggered with the 'save_post' hook. Yes, the field variable corresponds to an existing acf field. When I use an ID of image instead of an url, the field fills correctly.